# Bacon's cipher: An Intro to Steganography

Tags: code-golf, cryptography, steganography

*This little piggy went to market, this little piggy wrote some code...*

Ah wait, we're not talking about *that* bacon, we're talking about Sir Francis Bacon! Specifically, [the cipher Bacon devised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher) in the [late 1500s](http://www.cabinetmagazine.org/issues/40/sherman.php), as a method of hiding a message within another message, a method of [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

The cipher works by concealing the message in the **presentation** of text, rather than its content. First, the letters of your message are encoded into binary (from 0 to 25) as follows:

Note: Please use the following encoding in your code and do not worry about numbers, spaces, or other symbols in the input, though I may devise some bonus for those who include these characters in their encoding. If you do include other symbols, the letters must still occupy spaces 0-25 in the encoding.

```
Letter  Encoding
A       AAAAA
B       AAAAB
C       AAABA
D       AAABB
E       AABAA
F       AABAB
G       AABBA
H       AABBB
I       ABAAA
J       ABAAB
K       ABABA
L       ABABB
M       ABBAA
N       ABBAB
O       ABBBA
P       ABBBB
Q       BAAAA
R       BAAAB
S       BAABA
T       BAABB
U       BABAA
V       BABAB
W       BABBA
X       BABBB
Y       BBAAA
Z       BBAAB
```

Having encoded all of the letters in your message into the `A`s and `B`s above, you must now select two **typefaces** for your code. For this example, I will use normal text for typeface `A` and **bold text** for typeface `B`.

So the message

```
HELLOWORLD
```

is encoded to

```
AABBB AABAA ABABB ABABB ABBBA BABBA ABBBA BAAAB ABABB AAABB
```

And now we conceal this binary with a **carrier text**.

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs, gamboling in the fields where the shepherds keep watch.

It is alright if the carrier message is longer than the actual encoded message, though it cannot be shorter. Now we turn the carrier text into bold according to where the `B`s are in the encoded message,

> Th**e** **qu**ic**k** bro**w**n **fo**x **j**u**mp**s **ove**r **t**h**e** **l**az**y** **do**g**s**, gam**b**o**l**i**ng** in t**he** fields where the shepherds keeps watch.

Which without Markdown reads as

```
Th**e** **qu**ic**k** bro**w**n **fo**x **j**u**mp**s **ove**r **t**h**e** **l**az**y** 
**do**g**s**, gam**b**o**l**i**ng** in t**he** fields where the shepherds keeps watch.
```

Note that I did not use the punctuation in the carrier message to encode the message, but whether the punctuation is encoded or not is up to you/.

**Rules**

- Your input will be the message you to be encoded and a carrier message. If the carrier message is too short, return some sort of error message.
- You must select two typefaces for encoding `A` and `B`, such as UPPERCASE, lowercase, *italic*, **bold**, ***bold italic***, <s>strikethrough</s>, `in code format` and so on. You must use Stack Exchange's form of Markdown to encode these typefaces, i.e.

  ```
  UPPERCASE, lowercase, *italic*, **bold**, 
  ***bold italic***, <s>strikethrough</s>, `in code format`
  ```
- Your output must be your now-encoded carrier message, either shown with Markdown or shown without, as seen in the above example.
- You are only required to make an encoding algorithm. Any decoding algorithms you wish to provide are welcome, but **at time of writing** will not help or hinder your score.
- Your code must be a program or a function.
- This is code golf, so the smallest number of bytes wins.

As always, if the problem is unclear, please let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

Comment: So really there's no reason not to use upper/lowercase, since everything else costs more bytes

Comment: I think there's a typo in "we're not talking about *that* bacon", because surely you were talking about Kevin Bacon, so the "b" should be capitalised, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pyth, 47 bytes

```
Vsm.[05jxGd2r~zw0#I}Jr@z~Z+1Z0GBpJ)p?NrJ1J;>zZ
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vsm.%5B05jxGd2r%7Ezw0%23I%7DJr%40z%7EZ%2B1Z0GBpJ%29p%3FNrJ1J%3B%3EzZ&input=HELLOWORLD%0AThe+quick+brown+fox+jumps+over+the+lazy+dogs%2C+gamboling+in+the+fields+where+the+shepherds+keep+watch.&debug=0).

Explanation:

```
             ~zw                               - Get the first line of input and 
                                               - set z to the next line
            r   0                              - Turn it to lower case
  m                                            - Map each character
        xGd                                    - Get it's position in the alphabet
       j   2                                   - Turn it to base 2
   .[05                                        - Pad the start with 0's
 s                                             - Turn it to a 1d-array (flatten it)
V                                        ;     - For N in above array:
                 #                )            - While 1:
                      @z~Z+1Z                  - Get the current position in the 
                                               - second line and increment the position
                    Jr       0                 - Set J to it lowercased
                  I}          GB               - If it's a letter, break
                                pJ             - Otherwise, print it
                                    ?N         - Is the character code
                                               - (the current 1d-array) 1
                                      rJ1      - Get the current char uppered
                                         J     - Leave it lowered
                                   p           - Print the character
                                           >zZ - Print out the rest of the second input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>216</s> <s>211</s> <s>231</s> <s>225</s> 207 bytes

<s>This is a solution that uses normal text and Markdown-style italics for its two typefaces. And it encodes everything in the carrier message except the spaces.</s>

**Edit:** Had to fix the code so that the result would print correctly and added examples below the code.

**Edit:** Edited the code to previously worse uppercase/lowercase solution, due to problems in printing the italics correctly.

```python
def g(s,c):
 c=c.lower();w=[h.upper()for h in s if h.isalpha()];t=''.join("{:05b}".format(ord(i)-65)for i in w);r='';j=m=0
 while t[j:]:a=c[m];x=a!=" ";r+=[a,a.upper()][x*int(t[j])];j+=x;m+=1
 return r+c[m:]
```

**Examples**

```python
>>> g('HELLOWORLD', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs, gamboling in the fields 
where the shepherds keep watch')
'thE QUicK broWn FOx JuMPs OVEr ThE LazY DOgS, gaMbOlINg in THe fields where the shepherds keep watch'
```

**Ungolfed:**

```python
def bacon(message, carrier):
    # Lowers the case of the carrier message
    carrier = carrier.lower()
    # Removing all non-alphabetic characters and making the rest uppercase
    words = ""
    for char in message:
        if char.isalpha():
            words += char.upper()
    # Encoding the message
    binary = ""
    for letter in words:
        encode = ord(letter) - 65
        binary += "{:05b}".format(encode)
    # Encoding the carrier message
    result = ""
    bin_index = 0
    char_index = 0
    while bin_index < len(binary):
        letter = carrier[char_index]
        # If letter isn't a space and it needs to be encoded
        if letter != " " and int(binary[bin_index]): 
            letter = letter.upper()
        result += type + letter + type
        # The encoding only proceeds if letter wasn't a space
        bin_index += letter != " "
        # char_index increments whether or not letter was alphabetical
        char_index += 1
    # Return the encoded text and any leftover characters from the carrier message
    return result + carrier[char_index : ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 124 bytes

This requires the arguments to be in an ASCII-compatible encoding (e.g. ISO-8859.1 or UTF-8).  It modifies the carrier in-place, and returns 0 on success, or non-zero otherwise.  The encoding is `A`==lower-case and `B`==upper-case.  Unused carrier letters are set to upper.

```c
int f(char*p,char*s){int m=16;do{if(isalpha(*s)){*s|=32;*s-=(*p-1)&m?32:0;if(!(m/=2)){m=16;p+=!!*p;}}}while(*++s);return*p;}
```

#### Explanation

Including a test program.  Pass the letters to encode as the first argument, and the carrier string as the second.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* ASCII or compatible encoding assumed */
int f(char *p, char *s)         /* plaintext, carrier */
{
    int m=16;                   /* mask */
    do {
        if (isalpha(*s)) {
            *s |= 32;
            *s -= (*p-1)&m ? 32 : 0;
            if (!(m/=2)) {
                /* reset mask and advance unless we reached the end */
                m=16;
                p+=!!*p;
            }
        }
    } while (*++s);

    /* 0 (success) if we finished p, else non-zero */
    return *p;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int r = argc < 3 || f(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if (r)
        puts("~!^%&$+++NO CARRIER+++");
    else
        puts(argv[2]);
    return r;
}
```

Test output:

```c
$ ./66019 "HELLOWORLD" "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs, gamboling in the fields where the shepherds keep watch."  
thE QUicK broWn FOx JuMPs OVEr ThE LazY DOgS, gamBoLiNG in tHE FIELDS WHERE THE SHEPHERDS KEEP WATCH.
```

Comment: [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##VU9bT8IwFH7nV5wRJV1XFEbiA3UhRkk0IZIsJj4YTErpLrJutd0A5fLXZzd84bz0u51LeT/mvK4ljRBPmMaKtI9x91GhkQyGdzQ1LFMJQ1acYHMIRj7Bph@c@lj15GTkjwfEQfI28N1JkyfKCxwHq/HAGtjzDHWpFmWlc6zosU7zEiRLc9QApmNOoNkIGFuycTv7DthqTA1BG4B7GMHhABFqEh/DBYEW@AuXnsMRIO22sClVlQZ1T87nde/K87zXOTw@hOHLNLSk@98iMiMuGy5Hng8GTTvHun6ezmbz93k4e6rfEgHfVcrXsNTFNoeo2MFXJZWBYiM0lNbO2O8PrIrYEIiZXBZZmsf2P60XpSJbGdgmQotWMIlQllhtLYSCLSt5cvMH "C (gcc) – Try It Online")