# Tips for golfing in TypeScript's type system

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in TypeScript's type system? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to TypeScript's type system (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

If you're not familiar with programming in TypeScript's type system, the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) and [TypeScript Discord Server](https://discord.gg/typescript) are both great resources, as well as the [TypeScript Type System chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145771/typescript-type-system).

If you post any answers in TypeScript's type system, make sure to check out this [deadlineless 50-100 rep bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24106/87606).

Comment: Cheating? https://tkdodo.eu/blog/calling-java-script-from-type-script (that is, give the answer as a .js file designed to be read by tsc).

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your "remove comments" comment. Are you implying that comments don't count as golfed bytes? If so, use JSDoc for the types to get them for free. If not, can you clarify what you meant by that?

Comment: @jsejcksn That's pulled from the generic tips question; it means "don't say 'remove whitespace' or 'shorten identifiers', because that's applicable to all languages, not just TypeScript's type system"

Comment: @Joshua I'm not sure I understand. This is not about answers in TypeScript, but answers in *TypeScript's type system*, where the answer is a generic type that satisfies the challenge requirements. I'm not sure how calling out to JavaScript would be helpful for that.

Answer (score 9):

## Embrace the type errors

Type parameter constraints can often be replaced by a well-placed `//@ts-ignore` comment:

```
// 34 bytes
type Head<T extends any[]> = T[0];
```

```
// 33 bytes
//@ts-ignore
type Head<T> = T[0];
```

Comment: `type Head<T> = T[0&keyof T];` here would be 28 bytes; of course you can also delete the semicolon and two spaces in any of these solutions.

Comment: @kaya3 Indeed, but the `@ts-ignore` trick can replace multiple constraints simultaneously

Answer (score 5):

## Use `{}` instead of `any` or `unknown` where applicable

The type `{}` counterintuitively means "anything that is not `null` or `undefined`, so it can be useful for shorter constraints, if you don't care about `null`/`undefined`:

```
// 34 bytes
type Head<T extends any[]> = T[0];
```

```
// 32 bytes
type Head<T extends{}[]> = T[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use indexed access types as switch statements

Instead of

```
type Foo<T extends "a" | "b" | "c"> = 
    T extends "a"
    ? A
  : T extends "b"
    ? B
  : T extends "c"
    ? C
  : never
```

use

```
type Foo<T extends "a" | "b" | "c"> = {
  a: A,
  b: B,
  c: C,
}[T]
```

Note that in some cases this won't work for recursive types, as it might give the error `'foo' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation`.

Answer (score 3):

## Use unions as sets

You can use `T | U | V` as a set, or
`[T] | [U] | [V]` if you want to prevent merging (e.g. `number | 1` becomes `number`).

Set operations:

- Union: `A | B`
- Intersection: `A & B` for sets of primitives, or `Extract<A, B>` more more complex types
- Difference: `Exclude<A, B>`
- Map: `A extends A ? Foo<A> : 0` (if `A` is a type parameter)
- Map: `A extends infer B ? B extends A ? Foo<B> : 0 : 0` (if `A` is not a type parameter)
- Map: `A extends infer B ? [B]|[B] extends [A] ? Foo<B, A>` (if `A` is a type parameter and you need to preserve the reference to the full set)
- Empty set: `never`
- Size:

```
//@ts-ignore
type CountUnion<T,N=[]>=(T extends T?(x:()=>T)=>0:0)extends(x:infer U)=>0?U extends()=>infer V?CountUnion<Exclude<T,V>,[...N,0]>:N:0;
```

Comment: If A is assignable to the keys if an object you can do `{[K in A]:Foo<K>}[A]` to map over it

Answer (score 3):

## Use `any` or shorter types for template literals

```
type EndsInPeriod<I> = I extends `${any}.` ? true : false;
```

Saving around 3 bytes (instead of the alternative `${string}.`

Answer (score 2):

## Use type parameter defaults

Instead of

```
type RecursiveThing<T> = /* something recursive */
type Foo = RecursiveThing<Bar>;
```

Use

```
type Foo<T=Bar> = /* something recursive */
```

Instead of

```
type SomeConstant = /* something */;
type Foo<T> = /* something using that type */
```

Use

```
type Foo<T,SomeConstant = /*something*/>= /* something using that type */
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use tuples to do non-negative integer arithmetic

```
type IntToTuple<T, A extends any[] = []> = T extends A["length"] ? A : IntToTuple<T, [...A, 0]>;
type TupleToInt<T extends any[]> = T["length"];
type AddTuples<A extends any[], B extends any[]> = [...A, ...B];
type SubTuples<A extends any[], B extends any[]> = A extends [...B, ...infer C] ? C : never /* overflow */;
type MulTuples<A extends any[], B extends any[], C extends any[] = []> = A extends [0, ...infer A] ? MulTuples<A, B, [...C, ...B]> : C
type Add<A, B> = TupleToInt<AddTuples<IntToTuple<A>, IntToTuple<B>>>;
type Sub<A, B> = TupleToInt<SubTuples<IntToTuple<A>, IntToTuple<B>>>;
type Mul<A, B> = TupleToInt<MulTuples<IntToTuple<A>, IntToTuple<B>>>;

type Answer = Mul<Add<5, 2>, Sub<9, 3>>;
//   ^? - 42
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use stringification of number literal types to parse them

`` `${42}` `` becomes `"42"`, which can be worked with more easily:

```
type Mod2<N extends number> = `${N}` extends `${string}${"1" | "3" | "5" | "7" | "9"}` ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Didn't even realize this was Mod2! A similar type was used & golfed in [this even/odd challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113448/is-this-even-or-odd/260630#260630), but using an alternative array typing system instead.

Comment: Note that `\`${1.0}\`` becomes `"1"`

Answer (score 1):

## Use homomorphic mapped types to map tuples

```
type Foo<T> = [[[T]]];
type MapFoo<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Foo<T[K]>
}

type X = MapFoo<[1, 2, 3]>;
//   ^? - [Foo<1>, Foo<2>, Foo<3>]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use [this large collection of golfed utility types](https://gist.github.com/tjjfvi/e1b4de4cb17978e234bb391726edaa59)

Answer (score 1):

## A couple minor byte-saves

### Use `A extends{length:N}` instead of `A["length"]extends N`

This saves 1 byte off of decimal to unary conversion, among a few other things.

### When taking the first element and the rest of a tuple, use `{}` and indexing instead of `infer`

This saves 2 bytes if you only use the inferred value once. For example, this

```typescript
A extends[infer B,...infer C]?[B,C]:0
```

becomes

```typescript
A extends[{},...infer C]?[A[0],C]:0
```

---

I will add more if I think of / encounter any.

Answer (score 1):

## Combine multiple `extends` clauses into one

If you have multiple `extends` clauses where you're just extracting part of a tuple/string/whatever and know that the match will succeed and don't care about the failure case, you can combine many clauses into one:

```typescript
// Before:
type F<A,B>=A extends[infer D,...infer K]?B extends[5,6,infer F,...infer L]?[D,K,F,L]:0:0
// After:
type F<A,B>=[A,B]extends[[infer D,...infer K],[5,6,infer F,...infer L]]?[D,K,F,L]:0
```

In a case like this where you're just selecting part of each input, you can instead take the inputs as a tuple:

```typescript
// Even better:
type F<A>=A extends[[infer D,...infer K],[5,6,infer F,...infer L]]?[D,K,F,L]:0
```

This example is purposely useless, but this can come in handy in real challenges. One use case is when zipping two tuples:

```typescript
type F<A>=A extends[[infer X,...infer G],[infer Y,...infer H]]?[[X,Y],...F<A>]:A
```

I've used this technique in two submissions of mine: [Add two really big numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264953/108687) and [Order by Earliest Lower Digit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264956/108687).