# Order by Earliest Lower Digit

Tags: code-golf

Given two strings of digits, determine which string, if any, has the earliest digit which is lower than the other string's digit at the same index.

Do note that this differs from alphabetization, as shown in the following examples:

#### Examples

Given inputs `12345000` and `1233999999`, the second string would have the earliest lower digit.

```
12345000
1233999999
^          same value
 ^         same value
  ^        same value
   ^       second is lower
    ^^^^^^ irrelevant
```

Given strings `99` and `998`, neither has the earliest lowest digit, since `99` equals `99`, and the `8` has no digit to compare against.

```
99
998
^   same value
 ^  same value
  ^ irrelevant
```

#### Additional specification

- Input/output can be taken/given in any reasonable format.
- You can output any three consistent values to represent choosing the first input, the second input, or neither. (similar to [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem))
- Alternatively, you may use the standard output method of three-way comparison of your language of choice (if one exists)
- You may assume that there will be no leading 0s in input.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Test cases

Output is in the form `<` for first input, `>` for second input, and `=` for equal.

```
 999   999 =
 115   116 <
 116   115 >
 870   789 >
  33  3333 =
3333    33 =
  20  2100 <
  19  1200 >
2100    20 >
1200    19 <
1234  1234 =
4321  5432 <
5678  5432 >
  99   998 =
12345000  1233999999 >
```

Comment: Can I output an integer while positive means input1 > input2, negative means input1 < input2, and zero means equal? It is a common way to express `cmp` in many languages.

Comment: @tsh if that's reasonably common in your language, that sounds fine. I'll add a clause to the extra spec, good question.

Comment: In the test cases, the second input is the longer one. Can I assume this, or can the first input be longer?

Comment: @pajonk first input can be longer, sorry i didnt realize i hadnt shuffled them up enough, i'll add a few test cases for that

Comment: I think this challenge would be a bit better if we didn't have to account for equal input

Comment: May I take the string of digits as a list of unary numbers?

Comment: @noodleman that seems like reasonable enough I/O yea.
 As for not accounting for equal input... I feel like its a bit too ingrained into the challenge to remove at this point, with 14 answers, and its one of the few things that keeps this from just being a builtin check :P. I'm open to further commentary on that though

Comment: `116,115` returns `>`? Why is that?

Comment: @ValueInk `116,115` returns `>` because `115` has `5`, which is lower than `116`'s `6` in the same position. If it said anything else in the test cases, it was a typo, and should be corrected now. :)

Comment: yeah i misspoke it was saying `<` before

Comment: @ValueInk as you can see, it is a very easy typo to make XD

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda*l:cmp(*zip(*zip(*l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7dCoMwDIXv8xShV1bCaFqdreCTzF04N5lQf1Bvtpd3rcMDOQnkkHzzZ3tPo967qt59MzyeTerLdpiT9Nuf5qWUe9usrxUrvLWXdfb9lggSErtpwRb7EYUQzjkKBcw5MV/BFooK68AYMkGgFWlWCtgR69i1ySgaZEYz5cEhvxb2Px3H7BHKlVIxaNyh8OpEqEch7wiRYqUtchyYJSDivPTjlnRJWAT8Hw)

Uses `zip`'s truncating the to the shorter list. Test harness from @SuperStormer. Python 2 is needed for `cmp`.

Answer (score 9):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
±ḟIz-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DGhzvme1bp/v//P9pQx0jHWMdUx0zHAARjYSLmOpYIGAsA)

Input as lists of digits, output as `-1` (first wins), `0` (neither wins) or `1` second wins.
Would be 1-byte shorter to output negative, zero or positive, but [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) doesn't have a 3-way comparison operator so it seems this is ruled-out...

```
   z   # zip digits from each pair of inputs together
    -  # by subtraction,
 ḟ     # get the first element that is 
  I    # itself truthy (non-zero),
±      # output the sign of that (-1 or 1) or zero if it's empty
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 17 bytes

```
[ zip unzip <=> ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY@7DoJAEEX7/Yr7BWRnl6cPWmNjY6yMBUFQCmBZlhA1fjsO4CRz52QyzzLLXWuny/l4OmyQ9X2b96gz9/Raey8sjC2cexlbNQ7diIdtB1M1D2yF6MaPSJIEAKsAUcBIFArEkWSMYs5C69m1ZlScVSQlI3EbKUZS2p9R@8LXioCAgwjCKP7jPH1ZES@1gZRyqdfJYuILtV41XfGuDIZm1t0@xW0q14fSOjPwph8)

Outputs `+lt+` for first input, `+gt+` for second input, or `+eq+` for neither.

- `zip unzip` Truncate the longer input to the same length as the shorter one.
- `<=>` Compare.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

Expects two arrays of characters as `(a)(b)`. Returns `-2`, `-1` or `0` for `<`, `>` or `=` respectively.

```javascript
a=>b=>-a.some((c,i)=>d=c-b[i])^d<0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLLDoIwEEX3fkXTFU2ktJRnQvkRgkl5aDBIjRh/HwsL0GrLLE96MnduehUvMdaP7v50B9m005lPgucVz12BR3lrHac@dojnDa/dquhKdGoyMtVyGGXf4l5enLNTYIzBPDBNU1iiDawIAc8DgB9MIqWhLlIarWJmFJOY6GKcbBtzkwggY9@iAgvaiQqgr22EPiVkP6q6SCsHUv9DNEVVr1jwIy7IHhUGzKeaGCq2GxWGUZzYREur/z5AYo26HBMSsrY6A5Yus22c3g)

Or **31 bytes** if we output negative / zero / positive:

```javascript
a=>b=>a.some((c,i)=>d=c-b[i])*d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLLDoMgEEX3/QrCSpuKIOIjKfyIcYGvxsZKU5v@vlUX2tKCszzhZO7ccJUvOZSP9v70elXVY8NHyUXBhUSDutWOU55al4uKl16Rtbl7rMZS9YPqatSpi9M4GUIIzAPTNIW5u4EVucD3AeAHk0gI00VColU8G8UkxroYJ9tGYRIBpPRbnMCCdqICGGgbYUAw3o86XaSVA0nwIZqiTq9o@CMuyB4VhjQgmsgmthsVsihObKKl1X8fILFGXY5hGK@tzoCmy2wbxzc)

Comment: We all forgot the simplest solution

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 44 bytes

```r
\(x,n=nchar(x))sign(diff(x%/%10^(n-min(n))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBNCsIwEEZx6ykGpJBAi5mkPylYVx5DBKlEuzBCVehd3FTBQ-lp7DQtWDKLzOLxvZnJ41m3L1O87zcT6U-4ZU1oC1ue9jVrOL9WR8sOlTGsCZYBih2z0bmyzPKuXOY72xhWMsjzPASgBpzDAgq41CDmPUNMiCGmjq2IoWM6E8QyPeTWxKIBglIhPUr5UpAUlCiELwWkZVCO7F-KUsU9VLEnjZXEjiVd96RJmukJm246nq89KU1KhBBuqMr7mii6oPvMtnX9Bw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```
lambda s,t:cmp(s[:len(t)],t[:len(s)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU9bisMwDPzXKYShYINa_GgaO9CTtPnIZhs2kLqhdj96lv4ElmVvsffobWon3QGNBBqkmcfveI9fF6-n725__LnFbm2fq6E5f3w2GChW7Xnk4VANJ8-jqCkuYxC1eIv_2iacAu7x0G7COPSRM2ICu8sVW-w9Msacc5QKlCpIqR3YUlJpHRhDJgG0JK2kBOVI6dy12VIm2BqtqEgMxa60yzQfs7OokFJmoXEz0qt_C0fPRI2QXaQU2cdsswJEHK-9j7zjaSHeKaZp6S8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4.5 bytes (9 nibbles)

```
`$/|!$_-*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWKxNU9GsUVeJ1tSB8qPBNw2ilaEMdIx1jHRMdUx0DEIxV0oGJGQPFLJFhrFIsVCcA)

Input as lists of digits, output as `1` (first wins), `0` (neither wins) or `-1` second wins.
Would be 1-byte (2 nibbles) shorter to output negative, zero or positive.

```
`$/|!$_-*       # full program
`$/|!$_-*$$$    # with implicit args (I think*):
    !           # zip together
     $_         # arg1 & arg2
       -        # by subtraction,
   |            # filter the resulting list
        *$$     # by each element multiplied by itself
                # (zero and negatives are falsy in nibbles),
  /             # now fold over this list
           $    # returning the left-hand element each time
                # (so returning the first element),
`$              # and return the sign of this
                # (or zero if empty)
```

*I'm not quite sure why `$$$` is chosen for implicit args ([here](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/tutorial_minutiae.html) for the documentation), but happily it is and it works here...

Comment: Nibbles! That's clever.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>64</s> <s>63</s></sup> 62 bytes

```c
c;f(*a,*b){for(c=1;(*a&&*b)&c;c+=*a++>*b++)c-=*a<*b;return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbboJAEH33KyYkGlgg5SLKZtWXpm/9g2qaZV0sqUUDNCU1/HrpuCxUrZuwc2bOmTlkVrhiz/Nd2wqWmoQ7JLFO6aEwxdJnmE8mWJgIJuwl4ba9IoltW8LFZEESVsjqs8hBsKbN8go@eJabFpxGgAcLBCpZVq/8ZQNLOD0blFLDgWfD9yMV47mnYhiqEHSZr0VBOFVgGga@AtFsHitA/xSR53lGw24ck/@OMxXnMdWOvafvaddgANo3QuNrQGncS0KqzoU1yPooRSW3nbfvgOdA4MBdEOg@ccjLCsQbLwjeUrzLoms31vVTsK7pI37nZV3mYe@K7wTm2TrLt7LGNo9puIAy@5aH1Ox/ynrQBTJUGNi2UltqWPdqwx45jtOvp0Qbds0nPZ/c46FEOjW5A4l1TUgkhk3ddh4LlKSmMd6XDuAF7grGWxiX6xx3cJ7mADL9ptAEh220QzNq2h@R7vmubN2vXw)

*Saved a bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Inputs the digits as two wide-character strings.
Returns \$0\$ for `<`, \$2\$ for `>`, or \$1\$ for `=`.

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
≔✂θ⁰Ｌη¹θ≔✂η⁰Ｌθ¹ηＩ⁻›θη›ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8jOCczOVWjUEfBQEfBJzUvvSRDI0NTR8EQiAs1rblQVGUgqyqEqsoAqgooyswr0XBOLC7R8M3MKy3WcC9KTSxJLQKZCzINxs0AGQoE1v//m5qZWyiYmhgb/dctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal doesn't have any relevant builtins, so it struggles even to port @SuperStormer's Python 2 answer.

```
≔✂θ⁰Ｌη¹θ
```

Truncate the first string to the length of the second.

```
≔✂η⁰Ｌθ¹η
```

Truncate the second string of the length of the first.

```
Ｉ⁻›θη›ηθ
```

Compare the strings.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <strike>20</strike> <strike>17</strike> 12 bytes

*-5 bytes by Dlosc*

Returns -1 for first element, 1 for second and nothing if equal.

```
SG@FI_-BMZab
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZrgt0d3DzjdZ18oxKTIEJQmW3RhkbGxpZgoKMAZJuYGhgYxEJlAQ)

```
SG@FI_-BMZab­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
        MZab  # ‎⁡For each pair of digits in a, b
     _-B      # ‎⁢Return difference of digits
SG            # ‎⁣Push sign of
  @FI         # ‎⁤First truthy element
```

Comment: MapZip and lambda expressions are your friends here: [12 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhZrgt0d3DzjdZ18oxKTIEJQmW3RhkbGxpZgoKMAZJuYGhgYwPQBAA)

Answer (score 3):

## `sed -E`, 92 bytes

```
s/^(.*)(.).* \1(.).*/\2\30123456789/;s/^(.)(.).*\1.*\2.*/</;s/^(.)(.).*\2.*\1.*/>/;s/...*/=/
```

Assuming, that both numbers are in one line, space separated. Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't know how compare numbers, so we need to add the digit list and do some regexp backreferencing stuff. Option `-E` used for extended regular expressions to avoid twelve more bytes for escaping:

- `^(.*)(.).* \1(.).*/\2\30123456789/` removes everything but the first differing digit and adds the ordered digits, so `42 43000` would turn into `230123456789`
- `s/^(.)(.).*\1.*\2.*/</` turn the whole line into `<`, if the first digit appears in the digit list before the second one
- `s/^(.)(.).*\2.*\1.*/>/` does the opposite with `>`
- `s/...*/=/` cares for the rest (all legal lines that have not been replaced by `<` or `>` contain at least two characters (`..*` is one byte shorter than `.{2,}`)

Comment: You don’t need to add the `-E` to your byte count, just add it to your header before the byte count

Comment: @noodleman Thank you. Corrected and explanation added.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <del>93</del> <del>77</del> 54 bytes

Port of [@Dominic van Essen' R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264919/110802) in Julia.

Saved 39 bytes thanks to the comment of [@MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBCsIwEEX3nmLATQJtyCSNbdEW71EUBKlEahSt0Jt5AA9WO9WKAZNFZpHHf39yvDd2h11fF30Xl8wVbm8Ptr0J1vHlzR4c29u6ZmvRPR8ot8zFJ@uYE0JwzqsN5/3lal3bOFazCvI8jwBowPAEcyjgfAU5@2UQDTGIiw@zIgY9JkslMWk25ZTExD4EWkd0aR2WgaIghVKGZYBUGtWX@SNDpZMR0klQlmiFA2OGGZSZRZr5zN/Npm/MgjJqYqSU71I6H48f2b8A)

```
x->(n=ndigits.(x);sign(diff(@.x÷10^(n-min(n...)))[]))
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBRSsQwEAbg5@0pBnxJYDdkknbbovXdM4iCuE2NtLOSptCbeQAPVpPqioVNHjIQvsw/yfvU2xecl8U0ZqJXb8/EZp7tqOlb6vybYCfbWT@KcMpvs51r/eQIHsiz0XbEjHWjD8YYNouvT5QgnhmJw2DJDtPAiK8ra@m0fDhLvg932CPUdb0HiAWeOIcbaODsQGb/DWIRDeLx19xFgxtTlTKasrr0uY/msEWg9T5uWqfDQMVGCqVMhwHGoVH9mSthqHS@Ip0nw3KtMJgi1GRYcSyrrbn6sss3VsmwOEkhpfwZStfr2rZcvgE)

```
f=function(x)
    n=length.(digits.(x));
    return Int(sign(first(diff(x.÷10 .^(n.-minimum(n))))))
end
```

Comment: Use an anonymous function or `!` to save a bunch of bytes. [tips for golfing in Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/tips-for-golfing-in-julia)

Comment: Nice improvement, here is [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZBBCsIwEEX3nmLATQJtyCSNbdEW71EUBKlEahSt0Jt5AA9WO9WKAZNFZpHHf39yvDd2h11fF30Xl8wVbm8Ptr0J1vHlzR4c29u6ZmvRPR8ot8zFJ@uYE0JwzqsN5/3lal3bOFazCvI8jwBowPAEcyjgfAU5@2UQDTGIiw@zIgY9JkslMWk25ZTExD4EWkd0aR2WgaIghVKGZYBUGtWX@SNDpZMR0klQlmiFA2OGGZSZRZr5zN/Npm/MgjJqYqSU71I6H48f2b8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
$CM Z:aZb
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYrVZx9FaKsEqOSIHyo8NpoQyNjE1MdBRAVCxUEAA) Outputs -1 for `<`, 1 for `>`, and 0 for `=`.

#### Explanation

```lisp
      aZb  ; Zip the input numbers together, giving a list of pairs of digits
    Z:     ; Transpose into a pair of (equal-length) lists of digits
$CM        ; Fold on numeric comparison
```

The `CM` operator, when given two lists of digits, does almost what we want, but not if the lists are of unequal lengths. (If the shorter list is a prefix of the longer list, the longer list is considered to be greater.) So we zip the numbers together to clip to the length of the shorter one, then zip back again and compare.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 70 bytes

```
=@IFERROR(SIGN(TOCOL(1/(MID(A1,ROW(1:99),1)-MID(B1,ROW(1:99),1)),2)),)
```

Inputs in cells `A1` and `B1`.

Outputs `1` for first input, `-1` for second input and `0` for equal.

Assumes maximum string length of `99` characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 56 bytes

```
^(.+)(.*¶)\1
$2
^(¶.*|.*¶)$

(.).*
$1$*
(1*)¶\1
-
1+-?
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw9DgIhEIX7d4opMAE2S2ZgWaDyELZmo4WFjYWx9Fx7gL0YAr7k/WTyZd6Pz/N1ryd9uVHdtJuMdvbYzVWgPDZ97M5@x0UB2hlnoURZaLHm2Bs1Q6b5DKm1lELNEIkksiInppQLQqDQBM/khRlSSHxvHxbqgSV4odgScU35v8azPKDIzB0MZegH) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on spaces for convenience. Outputs `-1` for the first input and `1` for the second input having the earliest lower digit. Explanation:

```
^(.+)(.*¶)\1
$2
```

Remove any matching leading digits.

```
^(¶.*|.*¶)$
```

If at least one string is empty, then the there is no earliest lower digit. The rest of the program has no effect now that the output is empty.

```
(.).*
$1$*
```

Convert the first remaining digit of each number to unary, discarding the rest.

```
(1*)¶\1
-
```

Subtract the two unary numbers.

```
1+-?
1
```

Take the sign.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 21 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>b=>[a>b+f,b>a+f]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFdC4IwFIbv@xVjV4qV@/Bjg7Y/El1M0yjERUZ/f22GTmJ6rt4XHg7P2R7qo4b6dX@@D72@Nsa0QglZCXlWskrafSVV0l5MrftBd82x07eojYAbyDmH8S9PLQZpCoDYhXCM8wWOcTHhpyDOSrTASzZvlyEcQEpn3GbXNmQAJH47JBihTRmr60@FmHg8JGMBmi1x19ZlYEYJ9nhu65YMzIuShfGVl/n7JrYmM5rmyB03ZsrHmbebLw)

<!-- Before IO tweak: -->

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>b=>a>b+f|-(b>a+f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFdC4MgFIbv9yvEqyK2/MhSmP4Xazk2Iscau9p/b9ooY1jn6n3h4fAcveu3Hprn7fE69vbSjqORWqpaKq3qzHyOSa10ZtKxsf1gu/bU2WtiEuAHCiFg@stzS0GeAyAPMRxjtsIxLmf8HMV5hVZ4xZftKoYDSOmCu@zbjgyAJGyHBCO0K@N0w6kQk4DHZBxAizXu27YMLCjBAWeu7slAVlY8jm@8zN838S2ZyZQhf9yUqZhm2T5@AQ)

Same length as `a=>b=>a>b+{}|-(b>a+!0)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

port of [l4m2's answser](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265431)

```julia
a+b=(a>"$b:")-(b>"$a:")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7tboMwDPyfp7hlVZVoTCJQCkxN/u1Bwke1bAwQsK1vzxyvmqXYvvP5nPevIXhz23f/1FjlnTw0L1I/q4Y6T90urtOCgDBi6X03hLFflRag8EmTtLBY5yFsKvyRkWg/Z9Um0kqNR1odpu8e25vfKIUVP9PysbK2Iy2d5X5ewrgNo1LkqmEdOn3XPJAhjsd/hXy9zX279R0OrdSiH7sddV2TNmYrYExBwJgzLoILmHICVZkSKKs6AuR5fJSt4AKmyAAZyTKTptEAhqxNRsAJ5sBzJ5gDzy8E8lOUUbbilGcGKKjQpDiX1R3Eo/ePVvFOLIwIxNUijY7U5TUHHPAL)

#### nice solution but longer, 28 bytes

the same as [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264907)  <sub>*i swear i found it on my own*</sub>

```julia
a+b=cmp(zip(zip(a,b)...)...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7hToQwEIT/9ylGNBeIhFA4Dkiu/PNBOKixikAA9eLL43TvYpPd7cx@THn/Glyrr/vePl9M9zmHv@5WbXyJkiSR2tXrtMDBjVhs2w9utGsYKfAQizsYrPPgttDdTG/4rC4OTBDhkZ8O07fF9tZubG7Fz7R8rML2ZPm23OfFjdswhvI4TIM@ujMPDMTh8E8EL9fZdpvt8dQFkbJjv6Oua7K@GwWtCwqtTzgrGRCrUajKlKKsai@Q577YjZIBsRiAjFim09QHQDNaZxSNEg@yb5R4kP2ZIj96jN2oY55poODgpjiV1V34R@8/WhHzdJH6EN7yWg4a4A8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://www.gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 9 bytes

```
fo<<zW cp
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FN68zcgvyiEoUALiijsDQxJzMtMzVFIaAoNac0JZUrzcoq2jOvJFbXDkr5F6WkFmXmpS8tLUnTtVidZpuWb2NTFa6QXAARuVmVm5iZp2CrkJLPpaBQUKSgopCmEG2pY6ljEQumY9GFdQwgEjrm2CQt4ZIG6JJmOkZwSTMds1guiAsWLIDQAA)

Outputs as a native comparison value.

This zips the lists together comparing their values pairwise, then folds the results to get the answer.

### Reflection

This is rather short, however I have found myself desiring to zip and fold at once before, and so I might actually make a way to combine `fo` and `zW`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 49 bytes

```haskell
 ((head.(++[EQ]).snd.span(EQ==)).).zipWith compare
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDBaoNAEIbp1af4j7tkI67GREM9SikUilDoQTxsolZpYsS1FErfpBcplD5T-zTdVRPtwM4MHzP_7v4f34WQz9nh0H3mwddLmy-9HxuEFJlITbJYxGGUUFNWqSlrUZEwCgJKTWq-lfVj2RbYn461aLJh8_eqbjPZ7oXMJLZbxOS2ahn6dN-kWVNWTzQxppkAsQEVBL7vMww5jCgbKeeuopyvGe4eLtTbWIpuPDV7M1E4DlNH55kCbDVrc8v6pwCudrmt6aTAbWelqc6TwsqxOYOrylzBXW-8M52_YfyFN1fQiq6l71Kd4_fRbyWGcRRlpVyolTMt4hxEFqdXCDo2O4ogQIN3EMGwY2gorpe4GJgYg_FdN9Q_)

Comment: You would actually save bytes to do `import Data.Foldable;(fold.).zipWith compare` here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 74 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 9.25 bytes

```
Z~AEv¯fꜝh±
```

Returns -1 for first element, 1 for second and 0 for equal.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiWn5BRXbCr2bqnJ1owrEiLCIiLCJcIjEyMzM5OTk5OTlcIlxuXCIxMjM0NTAwMFwiIl0=)

```
Z~AEv¯fꜝh±
­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­

Z~A         # ‎⁡Zip and filter out falsy elements (trim numbers)
   E        # ‎⁢Covert string input to integers
    v¯f     # ‎⁣Calculate differences and flatten
       ꜝh±  # ‎⁤Output sign of first truthy element
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [Vyxal, 70 bits2, 8.75 bytes: `Z~AEv¯ꜝh±`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiWn5BRXbCr+qcnWjCsSIsIiIsIlwiNDNcIlxuXCI0MzMzXCIiXQ==) ([vyncoded](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md))

Comment: @lyxαl ah right forgot about string input + `~`. I believe you do need to flatten it though.

Comment: What's up with the diamond? I'm noob asking

Comment: @thejonymyster that's just a thing luminspire does :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a[0,b.size]<=>b[0,a.size]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5daoNAFIXfZxUHqdCCkfnxF6IbESlKNBFCEUcJaelK-hJK-9r9ZDc9oxmYO98598zM_fqZlvZ6--6L32Xud9kdu7IJ2o-mkkEb2uG9q_dF2VI1m_p85E6X03DucOxmKwBeQYGn19DO0zCGdjwPM-2JZl-xWVOMy2zh9ZUf2QAsNZu-PuDZty8efDCHNsAUwCvKvVdNdS26t8P23-3-hzzPAVcFlIqJSiUOkxVjgSyVxDRjAMa4bYxwhS4FXc2AVlISFR9Tmui0C2gpnHaocqKJXMBEIjJaATEPESdp9kA3yTpOtmZj6a6STL6ubex_)

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s Type System, 128 bytes

```typescript
type F<A>=A extends[[infer G,...infer N],[infer H extends 1[],...infer M]]?G extends[...H,...infer R]?R extends[]?F<[N,M]>:2:1:0
```

[Try it at the TypeScript Playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkCcBMFNNAIwJ6gKIENIBsCWsBnAF1ABkB7Ad3lABFcBzXEgWlAEYAmADiWSMIAoQUWQAHWKABiAHgCCAPgC8c0LAAeAgHbQCAbT24tAMxoBxADQA6G0dMIAcgF0LhkzQASazbB0EOei42VnY0ALJOTgD8Zt7aunrBHta27ggAStHpcb4J0bJ6DhYRCgBcnKXspQAMwoIgoMbk5AKQwg0AykYAxpJEABa4-kQYANaEoEZiAK4kGP4YoHjEoOTGoNNaWKha0wC2iPAEFqAAkgDke6BwxkZGDPVgBOR7kv2w2BIIohLD5KB7MZ9d6gATEFjdeYTWDzfDff6QGHQKzCH6SACqW0gyBkDhyflAuwO8BOqg08X87ECoCUoECChpoDkegARNhfAwBiynPjdKAHIJQKAokzBaBSqBMdtcSdEjY5Cd2E4FABuETiSQdIiQe4AFXIUuxpCGRAIMjFHV5-mIOq0DwZtMt5Ny-gABgASADeoUcVsJ+0OkAAvl6faB0kHXWKRXpDTiHAoTsEtbaGPq48biGb0gonGKJYE1WjQLrCER5H6bfcTgAhSva+4OulilloACO0ww2BZFhbUlwkBWQyWVHgPZbHVg3XIOkm-mwo8g46cegKKb1BqxyEzpvkidA67t6a3O7NNdzubVjxLZdAkIIQnVEhvxHYjNLxBkLK4AGYACwAKzVMBPagN+nA-j+ACcMGwSyCjXkKAB6URPpIH5EJw75ll+MGgSyMHcPBiGgChaEvkQP7YZ+37sAB+HsOwABsxENMhqHFhhf7UeWtEsSctH0QhbGkRxGoUQBPFftwADs1T4TJ3BQaxYDseRGFMVJLKQfhkE6cJqmiepZYyVpf4-pw7D4QB5mcCpQpGYIQA)

Generic type `F` takes type `A` which is a tuple of two lists  of unary digits. Output is 0 for equal, 1 for first is lower, 2 for second is lower.

### Explanation

```typescript
type F<A>=
  // match the first item (G or H) and rest (N or M) of each list in A
  A extends[[infer G,...infer N],[infer H extends 1[],...infer M]]
    ?G extends[...H, // if H fits in G,
      ...infer R]    //   let R be the difference.
      ?R extends[]   //   if R is empty,
        ?F<[N,M]>    //     recurse with N and M.
      :2             //   otherwise, 2 is smaller
    :1               // if H doesn't fit in G, 1 is smaller
  :0 // if neither has been chosen yet, they're equal
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN), 12 bytes

```
(⊑⍋-⍒)⌊○≠↑¨⋈
```

`¯1`:`<`, `0`:`≡`, `1`:`>`

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 43 bytes

```arturo
$[a b]->compare take a size b take b size a
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?x6oogQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.S0Ûн
```

I/O as two lists of digits. Outputs `-1` if the second is lower; `1` if the first is lower; and nothing if they're 'the same'.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fL9jg8OwLe///jzbUMdIx1jHRMdUxAMFYLqiIsY4lAsYCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Nc6xCsIwEAbgVymZFA65S5o2AbWTT9CxFFRwcHIoCN3EwVlc3cWhryAOeQGfoS8SL4ce5Pj4kzty6Dbb/S4e@0pl4@WWqaofz0O97uKsxnD/vGK4VhiG2Wo8PRbzZReeKpuE91RBbBrvPfBpoSGyQFSICpZluRKhdOnWGDBcIjFLI2hCTBMeSItSAFoyDoBkszY5pMbOjSaw3Nm2KN3f8g33e2wxjWpjvFTbfgE).

**Explanation:**

```python
.S    # Compare the digits at the same positions in the two (implicit) input-lists,
      # ignoring any trailing digits if the lists are of unequal lengths
      #  -1 if a<b; 0 if a==b; 1 if a>b
  0Û  # Trim all leading 0s
    н # Pop and push the first item, or an empty string if the list is now empty
      # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
Z~A∩÷₌><-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJ+IiwiIiwiWn5B4oipw7figow+PC0iLCIiLCJcIjk5OVwiLCBcIjk5OVwiID0+IDBcblwiMTE1XCIsIFwiMTE2XCIgPT4gMVxuXCIxMTZcIiwgXCIxMTVcIiA9PiAtMVxuXCI4NzBcIiwgXCI3ODlcIiA9PiAtMVxuXCIzM1wiLCBcIjMzMzNcIiA9PiAwXG5cIjMzMzNcIiwgXCIzM1wiID0+IDBcblwiMjBcIiwgXCIyMTAwXCIgPT4gMVxuXCIxOVwiLCBcIjEyMDBcIiA9PiAtMVxuXCIyMTAwXCIsIFwiMjBcIiA9PiAtMVxuXCIxMjAwXCIsIFwiMTlcIiA9PiAxXG5cIjEyMzRcIiwgXCIxMjM0XCIgPT4gMFxuXCI0MzIxXCIsIFwiNTQzMlwiID0+IDFcblwiNTY3OFwiLCBcIjU0MzJcIiA9PiAtMVxuXCI5OVwiLCBcIjk5OFwiID0+IDBcblwiMTIzNDUwMDBcIiwgXCIxMjMzOTk5OTk5XCIgPT4gLTEiXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 62 bytes

(but outputting the actual comparison characters instead of numbers, because... (that's the challenge spec??)) <sub><s>More like I was stupid and didn't read the comments and thought that that was necessary and didn't want to rewrite the code</s></sub>

```js
a=>b=>a.split``.find((u,i)=>u>b[i]?b=">":b[i]>u?b="<":0)?b:"="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7RCoIwFAbg@54iztUGJpvLaOLmg0TgpiYLcdK0119t5E3lufnPgY/Df1dP5ZqHmebDaNvOO@GVkFpIlbppMHNdpzcztggticFCLlJfzLXSAiQUYZVLOEooCK50AQJ8Y0dnhy4dbI8cAs454E8k@zfAuy9BaR4Epacoyl/BWAAsxP8XbBVbYC1x3iyRsWNOCIlNMsZ4nKglYP8C)