# Convert binary to unary

Tags: code-golf, binary, base-conversion

The title says it all; Given a number in the binary (base-2) number system, output the same number expressed in unary (base-1).

You should take the binary number as a string (optionally with a separator), list, or equivalent structure of digits, using any number or digit you like for the digits. The unary output can use any aforementioned format, and it should use a single-digit throughout the number but does not have to be consistent for different input values. You may choose to assume that the binary number will have no more than 8 bits, and/or that it will always be left-padded with zero bits to a certain length.

One method you may use to achieve this task is documented at [this esolangs.org article](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Binary_to_unary_conversion):

1. Replace all `1`s with `0*` (Using `*` as the unary digit; you may use any character.)
2. Replace all `*0`s with `0**`.
3. Remove all `0`s.

Here are some examples, using `0` and `1` for the binary digits and `*` for the unary digit:

- `1001` → `*********`
- `1010` → `**********`
- `00111111` → `***************************************************************`
- `00000` → (empty output)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: May the unary output be a mixture of multiple characters, instead of one distinct one (as long as its length is correct of course)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I’m going to say no, since it doesn’t really feel like base-1 at that point.

Comment: Fair enough. :) Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: `any reasonable input & output format` I'm guessing taking the input as an integer is not acceptable, but it would be good to state it explicitly.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt It has to be in binary, that’s kind of the whole point, I guess I thought that was obvious

Comment: In some programming languages, such as C, integer types are guaranteed to be binary.  For example, `uint32_t` is guaranteed to be a 32-bit unsigned type with no padding, with the place-value of the bits being 2^0, 2^1, etc.  Same for assembly languages for normal binary computers.  In such a language, if you choose to take an integer input, the challenge ends up being the same as [Output / Convert to unary number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263103) (where my answer is just an x86 machine code `memset(dst, '1', n)`.)

Comment: In other words, a binary integer in a register is a normal way for a function to accept binary numbers as input, and the most obvious / simple / efficient.  If you mean a **base 2 *string*** representation of a number, say that.  I agree with @LevelRiverSt on this. Your examples are string-like, but that could be assumed to be catering to languages that don't natively have binary integer types.  (e.g. Javascript, where numbers are floating-point, not binary integer.)  Also, a string of 1-bit digits can be packed into a register (or C `unsigned` int); that's a good way to store binary!

Comment: @PeterCordes there are existing answers with arrays of `0` and `1` as well as strings, but as you noted, the point of my comment was to recommend explicitly closing the loophole of calling an integer a binary representation.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt: Yes, that's the point of my comment, too, explaining to the OP why it's not obvious from the question's phrasing that an integer input isn't allowed.  Even their reply in a comment replying to yours doesn't close the loophole: an integer is in binary in many languages.  But despite that, I think they do intend to disallow integer types so this is a string-to-string conversion (or an array/list of digits).

Comment: (I always find it weird when people talk about "decimal" or "hex" numbers in asm questions on Stack Overflow when they're just talking about source code representations!  That's the same kind of sloppyness (or error) I often see in code-golf questions when discussing number representations in terms of golf langs. 
 With assembly language, I've had lots of experience thinking about terminology for discussing ASCII string (in some base) representations of numbers vs. binary integers vs. floating point, vs. various bigint formats vs. esoteric object-representations in some code-golf questions.)

Comment: Could I suggest a test case of `0000` to result in an empty output?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for explaining, now I understand I didn’t quite account for that interpretation. Clarifying now.

Comment: Thanks, good update.  (Other non-string integer representations not called "binary" I should have used for examples include [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and Gray code.  The existence of stuff like that is another part of why "binary integer" is meaningful when talking about numbers stored in registers or bytes in memory.)

Answer (score 11):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org)'s Type System, <sup><s>130</s></sup> 128 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type R<S,F,X>=S extends`${infer A}${F}${infer B}`?R<`${A}${X}${B}`,F,X>:S;type B<S>=R<R<R<S,1,"02">,20,"022">,0,"">
```

[Try it at the TypeScript Playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsDsDcFMBOAXUAjAltAhognqMpKAK476gC0oAjAEwAc6ey8AzqABRoHSSQATADbwAttmgBKAFDSQAAWRtKGAOZ9E8acjwAHeKABKAHgDKAGgBi5gBoA+ALynQ8AB6toAtgAMAJAG8sADMkUABBAF8AyyjA6BDEUAAhCO8AfhM-f0iAm1iU7ytbOwAuUwBuHX1ks0cTerNzGnMAIgAGOha7czo21o7O7r6WrtkqgwAVdmQ20Acakbs5MFBQAD007T1J6Zo5hZpRkFX1zfHQKbZkOn2k4xaaNsejldOt6svkAGZb+8enl4nDbvHZXAAsv3aTxoMJhgNWwKAA)

Uses 2 as the unary digit. Defines a utility type to recursively remove all occurrences of a given string with a different string, and then defines the main type which is a series of nested calls to the utility type.

Comment: Do you need `//@ts-ignore`? Seems like there's a warning, but not an error, given that it works with and without that ignore comment. Related: [Untyped functions in static languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11223/98937) "As code compiles just fine without them, there is no need to add them in."

Comment: @Samathingamajig This is the standard for TS submissions but it might make sense to change it

Answer (score 10):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
BI
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJCSSIsIiIsIlwiMTAxMFwiIl0=) or [see it with asterisks instead](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJCSSIsIsOwXFwqViIsIlwiMTAxMFwiIl0=)

Same as my Thunno 2 answer.

##### Explanation

```python
BI  # Implicit input
B   # From binary
 I  # That many spaces
    # Implicit output
```

Comment: Power `BI`, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

## Excel, 20 bytes

```
=REPT(9,BIN2DEC(A1))
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
f l=10^foldl((+).(2*))0l-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcZBCoAgEEDRq7jUUtH2HqEThMFQWdJYkp2/KVzE48PfoOwLIlFg6KwZw4kzct4KzbtGCIPKUoJ4MMcS5J7nKx63DoINg5XmY72s91Xv5z09U0BYC6kp5xc)

Input is a list of `0/1`, output is a number like `9999999999` made of the digit `9`.

Haskell is interesting for this challenge because it lacks base-conversion built-ins without imports, so we have to do it ourselves. This answer folds the operation `\n b->n*2+b` over the list of bits to get a number `k`, then computes `10^k-1` to get a number made of `k` 9-digits. The 9's trick is shorter than more natural methods like `replicate k 1` or `1<$[1..k]` or `take k[0,0..]`.

It's slightly longer to do the power-of-10 within the fold and decrement after:

**27 bytes**

```hs
pred.foldl(\n b->n^2*10^b)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcZBDkAwEEDRq8wSQVr7uoET0Calihg1Kec3hERefvJne6wjInvVMcXRlX5Hh0kXoC/qYKpMCtOnkje7BFCwWWogobiEs/QptK3MxUPqHN59@vanNV@DRzsdXAxENw)

though if we bend the rules and represent bits as `1` or decimal `10`, we can do

**21 bytes**

```hs
pred.foldl((*).(^2))1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYdBDkAwEAC/ssdWqlF3T/CCqqQpRaza4P0WCQeZySQz@n3uETlWDdPWdzqu2KEQmdSiLaU0vPgpQQWLpxoEbVM6dJRgrSmUeSicgnfufPPTOT5DRD/snAeiCw)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
foldl(\s b->s++s++[1|b])[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPy0/JyVHI6ZYIUnXrlhbG4iiDWuSYjWjY//nJmbmKdgq5CYW@GoUFGXmleilaSpER4cUlabquCXmFMNIkECsjgKyBIIJl8BFxMb@/5eclpOYXvxfN7mgAAA)

Input is list of Booleans, output is a list of 1's. This iterates over the list of Booleans, each time doubling the current string then appending an additional `1` if the bit is `True`.

Comment: I think using other things to represent the digits should be okay, so your 21 byte version is valid.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 21 bytes

```python
lambda s:"*"*int(s,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSklLSSszr0SjWMdI839BEYiZpqFkaGBooKSp@R8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 3 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes list of binary digits and returns list of `1`s

```apl
⊥⍴≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HX0ke9Wx51Lvyf9qhtwqPevkddzY961wDFDq03ftQ28VHf1OAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NwVDBAAgNuSAsIAaywCIICAA)

`⊥` the base-2 evaluation

`⍴` **r**eshapes

`≡` the depth (nesting level, which is always 1 for a list)

Answer (score 5):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) Type System, 79 bytes

```js
type B<S>=S extends`${infer Q}${infer V}`?`${B<V>}${B<V>}${Q extends"1"?Q:""}`:S
```

[Try it on the Typescript Playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgPAZQHwF4FQgD2BAdgEwGcADAEgG8BLXAMwgCcoBFAXwursYDUXiB+MuXhckbIXBFimGbHiIAiAIzy+TAFzz5vNQgBQu0JCgAVCIWAAGKClhxNSXQHpHUVwD0+B8NFPnF12yV5B2dXKA8vI19gACYA+HkLRSTgpxd3T0MfM2AAZni7ZJSQ9PDM7xMcgBYCpUV6+osLVNCMoA)

Note: This works with little-endian binary, not big-endian.

While the algorithm in the post allows simply performing replacements, we can take advantage of Typescript's ability to anchor string matches for a much simpler algorithm.

Essentially,  `` S extends`${infer Q}${infer V}` `` matches the first character `Q` and the rest of the string `V`. We recurse on `V` twice, and append a 1 if `Q` is a 1.

Comment: Wow, nice, good job! I totally missed this

Comment: I can’t use the TS playground on the device I have access to right now, could you confirm this doesn’t hit the recursion limit for any 8-bit binary numbers? Thanks

Comment: @noodleman While this has time complexity proportional to the size of the output, the recursive calls only go log(n) layers deep, so it wouldn't hit the recursion limit until 50-bit binary numbers (and it'd take multiple years to do that anyway)

Answer (score 5):

## x86+MMX machine code, 10 bytes

Despite the question only saying the input has to be "binary", comments seem to imply they're thinking of a text string of base-2 digits, not 1-bit digits packed into an integer which a computer can already use directly as an unsigned integer.  If that's allowed, see my 7-byte answer on [Output / Convert to unary number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262975/output-convert-to-unary-number/263103#263103).

This is that answer plus conversion from 8 bytes to an 8-bit integer, by extracting the high bit of each input.  Input is in `mm0`, an MMX vector register, with the lowest element being the *least* significant.  (If stored to memory, this would be opposite of standard printing order where the most significant goes first, at the lowest address of a string.)

```
   ; machine code    |   NASM source
                       ; RDI or ES:EDI = output buffer of size n+1
                       binary_to_unary:
                       ;  pslld    mm0, 7     ; 4 bytes. For input digits '0' / '1', shift the low bit to high
  0FD7C8                pmovmskb ecx, mm0    ; pack the binary digits into an integer in ECX
                                             ; memset(dst, '1', n)
  B031                  mov      al, '1'
  F3AA                  rep stosb
  880F                  mov byte [rdi], cl   ; terminate the C-style string
  C3                    ret
```

For ASCII `'0'` / `'1'` input, we'd start with `pslld mm0, 7` to shift the low bit to the high position of each byte.  Also, if the digit-string was loaded from a string in memory in printing order (most significant at lowest address), we'd need to byte-reverse.  In that case scalar code to read input would be smaller than `movbe` or load+`bswap` in an integer register + `movq mm0, rax`, or `psufb` with an 8-byte vector constant.

In this current version, our input string in an MMX register is effectively big-endian, most significant digit in the highest element number (on the left when writing it in [the notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351087/convention-for-displaying-vector-registers) Intel manuals use to document vector instructions).

## x86 scalar machine code, 14 bytes, input from a C string in printing order

- RDI or ES:EDI points to an input buffer of base-2 ASCII digits, terminated by a `0` byte (or any byte below ASCII `'0'`), padded to at least 32 digits.
- RSI or ES:ESI points to an output buffer of size n+1, will be filled with `'0'` digits and terminated with a `0`.

Callable from C with the x86-64 System V calling convention as `void binary_string_to_unary(const char *binary_src, char *unary_dst);`.  Use the x32 ABI for 32-bit pointers, or change the `mov edi, esi` to `push rsi`/`pop rdi` to copy a 64-bit register with the same code size.  (Or use the same binary machine code in 32-bit mode.)

```
               binary_string_to_unary:
  B030           mov      al, '0'    ; input digit to compare against, also the output digit
               .loop:
  11C9           adc    ecx, ecx     ; ECX = 2*ECX + CF
  AE             scasb               ; set FLAGS like cmp al, [rdi] then increment RDI.   CF=1 for digit='1', CF=0 for digit='0'.
  76FB           jbe   .loop         ; while('0' <= digit);   i.e. while digit >= '0', false for digit = 0 terminator

  89F7           mov   edi, esi      ; x32 ABI, or for 32-bit mode.  For full 64-bit pointers, push rsi / pop rdi 
  F3AA           rep stosb           ; memset(rdi, al='0', rcx)
  880F           mov   [rdi], cl     ; terminate the C-style string
  C3             ret
```

Note that we don't `xor ecx,ecx` before the loop.  Instead we rely on the input string being '0'-padded to at least 32 digits, so the previous contents get shifted out.

There might be a way (with same code size) to take the input pointer in RSI like you'd expect from the traditional meanings of those registers, perhaps with `lodsb` / `cmp al, '0'` (3 bytes instead of 1 for scasb, but avoiding the 2-byte `mov edi, esi` after the loop).  Change the branch conditions accordingly for comparing in the other direction.  Except that would get CF=0 for digit='1'.  So maybe `add al, 255-'0'` so '1' produces a carry-out but '0' doesn't?  And the terminator is a value that results in some FLAGS condition that the other two don't, perhaps a signed overflow and/or the sign flag.

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I came here for!

Comment: The question allows different unary characters for different inputs, but for implicit-length string output we need to avoid AL=0 for non-zero input.  So I don't see a way to save the `mov al, '1'` or reduce it to 1 byte.  Taking another input there and doing `xchg eax, edi` would be 1 byte, but would just swap in whatever garbage is there.  `salc` with non-zero CF could work, or `lahf` to get non-zero AH if we were using `stosw` UTF-16 strings in 16-bit mode.  (`stosw` takes 2 bytes in other modes.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you should checkout the [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck) question. I got to [104 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264220/100240) but would be cool to see what you come up with.

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 53 bytes

Takes a string of `0` and `1` characters, outputs a string of `1`s.

```
>,[>-[<->-----]<+++<[->++<]>>,]>-[<+>-----]<--<[->.<]
```

**Explaination**

```
>,[                 read a character
>-[<->-----]<+++    subtract 48 to turn it into 0/1
<[->++<]            double the existing sum and add it to the new digit
>>,]                read another character and repeat if not EOF
>-[<+>-----]<--     make 49
<[->.<]             print 49 the necessary number of times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTifaTjfaRtdOFwRibbS1tW2ide2AZKydnU4sSE4bJqerC5LSs4n9/9/QwMAQAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
B1ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/38nw4Y7u////RxvoGOgYImAsAA)

```
  ḋ  # interpret input as binary digits
B    # and convert this to base
 1   # 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

As a list of '1's:

```
Table[1,2^^#] &
```

Anonymous function. Would probably be 10 bytes in the hypothetical mthmca golfing language.

Comment: The output can be a list. Also, the character doesn't have to be "*" if using, say, a digit, would be shorter.

Comment: @noodleman Thanks. Revised accordingly and saving 13 bytes.

Comment: What version does this work in? AFAIK `^^` only works in number literals.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](https://clang.llvm.org), <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=0;*++s;i+=i+*s-48);i&&printf("%0*d",i);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OScxL33BgqWlJWm6FjetMq3TNJIzEou0ijWr0_KLNDJtDay1tLWLrTO1bTO1tYp1TSw0rTPV1AqKMvNK0jSUVA20UpR0MjWtayEm3GJsA0oo5CZm5mloKlRzKQABTG1MXpBrcKhPiIKClZKmNVgKKGpgYAgGMCGEateIAFfnEFcXKy3KQEweyGxinGIIhES5g3gj8RhHgrvwOQrJmKLUktKiPAUDay5odMAiFgA)

Comment: It feels like there should be a way to omit the `,0` arg to printf and just have it print whatever garbage was left.  Or just spaces?  But `printf("%*c",i)` prints a byte of garbage at the end, and we probably can't consider that a "terminator".  Perhaps `for(;i--;)puts("");` to use newline as the unary character?

Comment: Or if you want to write a function that returns a string instead of printing, perhaps `memset(s,7,i);s[i]=0;` to replace the input string with that many ASCII "BEL" characters and a terminator, but that might not be shorter.  Or `memset(...); return i;` for an explicit-length string.   (And relies on the caller to allocate a large enough buffer without having parsed the string of binary digits, so only a larger fixed-size buffer could work.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good ideas, but I only managed to get the first one to work (leaving off `,0`). Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 22 bytes

```r
\(x)rep(1,strtoi(x,2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMG6pMy8xKLKkvxSEGW7tLQkTddiW4xGhWZRaoGGoU5xSVFJfqZGhY6RpiZEcjeKDo0KWyUDA0MwUIKqWLAAQgMA)

Convert from binary and repeat `1` that many times.

Unfortunately shorter than the more-interesting (I think):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(x)Reduce(\(a,b)c(a,a,b[b]),x,{})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMG6pMy8xKLKkvxSEGW7tLQkTdfiplKMRoVmUGpKaXKqRoxGok6SZjKQBNLRSbGaOhU61bWaUJXKKPo1KmyTNQx0DHQMEVATqnTBAggNAA)

Input is a vector of binary digits; fold over (`Reduce`) this from the left, starting with an empty vector (`NULL`), at each step duplicating whatever we've got so far, and appending the new digit if it's a `1`.

Comment: [-2 on the second one](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMG6pMy8xKLKkvxSEGW7tLQkTdfiplKMRoVmUGpKaXKqRoxGok6SZjKQBNLRSbGaOhU61bWaUJXKKPo1KmyTNQx0DHQMEVATqnTBAggNAA) by using `{}` for the empty vector.

Comment: @pajonk - Ah, yes, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 15 bytes

```
1 or rand(.5sum(Ans2^cumSum(1 or Ans
```

Input is taken as a list of `0`s and `1`s in little-endian binary in `Ans`. Output is a list of `1`s.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```ruby
->(b){?**b.to_i(2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmCrEPNf104jSbPaXksrSa8kPz5Tw0izVuF/QWlJsUKaXnJiTo6GkqGBgaGS5v//AA)

It goes from binary to a decimal integer, and becomes a factor by which an asterisk char is multiplied.

(Idea to switch to char from string was suggested by [Travis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75203/travis). Thanks!)

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes | (old)

```ruby
->(b){"*"*b.to_i(2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmCrEPNf104jSbNaSUtJK0mvJD8@U8NIs1bhf0FpSbFCml5yYk6OhpKhgYGhkub//wA)

Same as the upper one, but the upper one has been improved.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Thank you! Glad to be here :)

Comment: You can remove a byte by using `?*` for `"*"` instead of quotes.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 21 bytes

```javascript
x=>'x'.repeat('0b'+x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ42wSiX6H3cVsSiFOVGK3X@@98YszjaevvfFNmoNKOEHADuoUF4K7YBOjR@I2uZKtXDAjeOcdGKM/)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 4 or 5 bytes

```
#.##
```

Uses the length of the input digit list for the unary digit.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxRFlPWRnCvGmiyZWanJGvoKOnkKamZ6dgCFRsACStwSwQBrIMFJT1MvPKFAwMDMEAonfBAggNAA)

Like 05AB1E, uniformity is one extra byte, with alternatives.

- Infinity [`#.#_:`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxVFlPOd4Kwr5posmVmpyRr6Cjp5CmpmenYAhUbQAkrcEsEAayDBSU9TLzyhQMDAzBAKJ3wQIIDQA) or [`_#~#.`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxNF65TlkPwr5posmVmpyRr6Cjp5CmpmenYAhUbQAkrcEsEAayDBSU9TLzyhQMDAzBAKJ3wQIIDQA)
- Any digit [`#.#1:`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxVFlP2dAKwr5posmVmpyRr6Cjp5CmpmenYAhUbQAkrcEsEAayDBSU9TLzyhQMDAzBAKJ3wQIIDQA) or [`1#~#.`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmux1FC5TlkPwr5posmVmpyRr6Cjp5CmpmenYAhUbQAkrcEsEAayDBSU9TLzyhQMDAzBAKJ3wQIIDQA)
- Level (direct port of [Adam's APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264024/110888)) [`#.#L.`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxVFlP2UcPwr5posmVmpyRr6Cjp5CmpmenYAhUbQAkrcEsEAayDBSU9TLzyhQMDAzBAKJ3wQIIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 15 bytes

```perl
$_=9x oct"0b$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tayQiE/uUTJIEklXun/f0MDA0MuQwNDAy4gAwz@5ReUZObnFf/XLcgBAA)

Outputs 9 (my chosen char) the number of times given in the input binary number.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 28 bytes

```powershell
"*"*[Convert]::ToInt32($_,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkliUXlyjWv1fSUtJK9o5P68stagk1soqJN8zr8TYSEMlXsdI83/t//@GBgaGCoYGhgYKQAYYABlAAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 22 bytes

```
{"*".repeat(toInt(2))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xDsIwDET3foWVKUEQJYxIsHVgYuALoqqBiOBUkUFCVb49OKW85Xw@WedHohiw@hfC0wWUCuYOmLeLwMuBQsIDXCkHvGlOd6fVwBHqLDZC53EaHUlKZyS5V6rUdu9ydp@Ll8IaY8UWWK1pynbhNzNCaZ9y74b7Wt2YuIIiyv8LMpBSS1q6Ur8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ḃṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU4MiVFMSVCOSVBMyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEwMTAmZmxhZ3M9) or [see it with asterisks instead](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU4MiVFMSVCOSVBMyZmb290ZXI9JUMzJUIwJyp2JmlucHV0PTEwMTAmZmxhZ3M9)

Uses spaces.

##### Explanation

```python
Ḃṣ  # Implicit input
Ḃ   # From binary
 ṣ  # That many spaces
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
⍘Ｓ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfwzCsoLYGyNXUUjDQ1rf//NzQwNPivW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a string of `-`s. Explanation:

```
 Ｓ  Input string
⍘   Convert from base
  ² Literal integer `2`
    Print as row of `-`s
```

Unfortunately `BaseString(2, InputString())` performs a different operation, which means I can't use implicit input to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 23 bytes

```arturo
$=>[@.of:from.binary&1]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?lpQeWe)

Returns a list of digits.

```
$=>[             ; a function where input is assigned to &
    from.binary& ; convert input from binary string to decimal integer
    @.of: _ 1    ; create list of that many 1s
]                ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 16 bytes

```
1
01
+`10
011
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w35DLwJBLO8HQAEgD2Vz//xsaAEUMDUAiQCEQAAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: A direct interpretation of the method given in the question, except using `1` instead of `*` for obvious reasons. Note that the method in Retina's own tutorial is slightly different preferring to use `^0+` presumably for a slight performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Since outputting the unary as a single character is required, there are a couple of 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternatives:

- Output as spaces: `Cð×` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@fCGw9P//zc0MDAEAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/58MbDk///6hhmdLh/Uo6/6OVDA0MDJV0gJShAZACcsBAKRYA);
- Output as 1s: `$C×` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fxfnw9P//DQ0MDAE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f8YFefD0//rcIFEucozMnNSFYpSE1MUMvO4UvK5FBT08wtK9CGaoRSaeTYKKmC1ean/DQ0MDLkMDQwNuIAMMOACAA);
- Output as 0s: `ÎC×` - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cJ/z4en//xsaGBgCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f/Dfc6Hp//X4QKJcpVnZOakKhSlJqYoZOZxpeRzKSjo5xeU6EM0Qyk082wUVMBq81L/GxoYGHIZGhgacAEZYMAFAA);
- Output as any digit (as a list of characters): `CÅ9` (where the `9` could be any other digit) - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@XCr5f//hgYGhgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/58Otlv91/kcrGRoYGCrpAClDAyAF5ICBUiwA).

If a mixture of multiple characters for the unary output would have been allowed, since only the length matters in unary, it could have been 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) with:

```
C∍
```

Outputs a mixture of `1`s and `0`s (depending on the input) for its unary output.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@VFH7///hgYGhgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf@dHHb3/df5HKxkaGBgq6QApQwMgBeSAgVIsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
C   # Convert the (implicit) input binary-string to a base-10 integer
 ð× # Pop and push a string with that many spaces
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
  
$   # Push 1 and the input binary-stringC×
Î   # Or alternatively, push 0 and the input binary-string
 C  # Convert the binary-string to a base-10 integer
  × # Repeat the 1 or 0 that many times as string
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)

C   # Convert the (implicit) input binary-string to a base-10 integer
 Å9 # Pop and push a list with that many 9s (or any other digit)
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
C   # Convert the (implicit) input binary-string to a base-10 integer
 ∍  # Extend/shorten the (implicit) input binary-string to that length
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

Some different alternatives are available:

- Output as `*`s: [`å⌂*`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w0kc9TVr//ysZGhgYKnEBKUMDIAXkgIESAA); [`åÄ⌂`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w0sMtj3qa/v9XMjQwMFTiAlKGBkAKyAEDJQA); [`å{⌂`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w0upHPU3//ysZGhgYKnEBKUMDIAXkgIESAA).
- Output as spaces: [`å *`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wUgWt/@pK8YfW/FcyNDAwVOICUoYGQArIAQMlAA); [`åÄ`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w0sMtCv/VleIPrfmvZGhgYKjEBaQMDYAUkAMGSgA) ; [`å{`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w0mqF/7XqSvGH1vxXMjQwMFTiAlKGBkAKyAEDJQA) .
- All six above should have been also possible with a binary-list instead of binary-string as input, replacing the `å` with `ä`, but unfortunately there seems to be a bug with leading `0`s apparently.. - [Try `ä⌂*` online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wkkc9TVr//0cb6hgAoWEsF5gFxEAWWAQBYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
å    # Convert the (implicit) input binary-string to a base-10 integer
 ⌂*  # Repeat that many "*" as string
  *  # Or alternatively, repeat that many spaces as string
     # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)

å    # Convert the (implicit) input binary-string to a base-10 integer
 Ä   # Pop and loop that many times, using the following character as inner code-block:
 {   # Or alternatively, use everything after it as code-block:
  ⌂  #  Push an "*" to the stack every iteration
     #  Or alternatively, push a space character to the stack every iteration
     # (after which the entire stack is joined together and output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 32 bytes

```
echo str_repeat('*',bindec($i));
```

Where `$i` is the input string.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 18 bytes

```
/1/0*//*0/0**//0//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X99Q30BLX1/LAEgBaQN9fUMDIPz/HwA)

I didn't write this, I borrowed it from [the esolangs wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki////). Here's how it works:

Let's start with the string `10101`, which represents 21.

`/1/0*/` replaces `1`s with `0*`. The string becomes `0*00*00*`. In this, each `*` represents a sort of place value - for example, the first `*` has 4 `0`s after it, so it represents 2<sup>4</sup> = 16.

`/*0/0**/` replaces each `*` before a zero with two copies of it after the zero, each with half the place value. The first replacement this would do would be replacing `0*00*00*` with `00**0*00*`, replacing a `*` representing 16 with 2 `*`s each representing 8.

In `///`, replacements are repeated until nothing is left to replace, so this will eventually result in a string with some amount of 0s at the start, followed by 21 `*`s each representing 1.

Finally, `/0//` removes the leading zeros, leaving just 21 `*`s, which is the output in unary.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 28

```
:
s/1/0u/
s/u0/0uu/
t
s/0//g
```

Implementation algorithm as per the question.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYnBEcAwCMP@LGPzzTztdYA08xMBD1sW@32qVmylfEQfA9APW/qqMtKRnZTpmbNbtDEKmAP6cQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 17

```bash
[q]sz2iA?^9/d0=zn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYYq2Qks@VmpyRr6AS5BrgE1mTkqygm6oQ8z@6MLa4yijT0T7OUj/FwLYq7z9IFVdKfl7qf0MuQwMuQxAJpAyANJgL5oMEQCIGQCEgAwyADJAEAA)

#### Explanation

```bash
[ ]                # define a macro to...
 q                 #   quit (i.e. print the empty string)
   sz              # save the macro to register z
     2i            # set input radix to 2 (binary)
       A           # pop 10
        ?          # read input
         ^         # exponentiate 10 to the power of the input
          9/       # divide by 9.  This gives a number consisting of n 1s, or 0
            d      # duplicate top of stack
             0=z   # if equal to 0, call macro stored in z register to print the empty string
                n  # otherwise print the unary number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```julia
~x="*"^parse(Int,"0b"*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CVklLKa4gsag4VcMzr0RHySBJSatC879DcUZ@uUKdkqGBgaESF5dDYnFxalEJTEDB1lZBSQsGlFCkDQ3QpFHkgbrBAF0NWQDVYCCAmKr0HwA)

Generally, any base other than 10 needs to be specified: `parse(Int,x,base=2)`. Two bytes are saved by appending a `0b` [integer prefix](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Integers) instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 42 bytes

```
([]){{}({}<>({}){})<>([])}<>{({}[(())])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6VrO6ulajutbGDkhoAhGQARQE8quBAtEaGpqaQF517f//hgqGCgYKhgA)

The code works by accumulating the values of partial sums on the second stack, then it expands the second stack from the single value n, to n copies of 1.

```
([]) Push the stack height
{ While the stack is not empty
  {} pop the stack height
  (
    {} pop the top of the stack
    <> Jump to the second stack
    ({}){} Add the top element of the second stack twice, popping it
  ) Push the sum
  <> 
  ([]) Push new height
}
<> On the second stack:
{ While n>0
  ({} Pop n
    [(()) Push 1
    ] add -1
  ) Push n-1
}{} Pop the zero
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 46 bytes

```
a::=:::
1::=0*
*0::=0**
*>::=!>
!::=~*
::=
a>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/P9HKytbKyorLEEgbaHFpGYBpIMMOyFC041IEUnVaXECSK9GO6/9/Q0MDBQA)

Answer (score 1):

## Uiua, <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
⊚°⋯⇌
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oqawrDii6_ih4wKRiBbMSAxIDAgMV0K)

Convert from binary, use `⊚` where to change this to an array of N 0s.

Before I knew about `°⋯`:

### Uiua, 13 bytes

```
×0⇡/+×ⁿ:2⇌⇡⧻.
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAgw5cw4oehLyvDl-KBvzoy4oeM4oeh4qe7LgpGIFsxIDEgMCAxXQo=)

Multiply by powers of 2, sum, range, multiply each by 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, 48 bytes

```swift
let f={{String.init}()("*",Int($0+"",radix:2)!)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 33 bytes

```lua
print(('*'):rep(tonumber(...,2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ11LXdOqKLVAoyQ/rzQ3KbVIQ09PT8dIU1Pz////hgYGhgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a binary string, outputs a string of spaces.

```
Íç
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=zec&footer=5zE&input=IjEwMDEi) (Footer replaces spaces with `1`s)

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), 65 bytes

```
=d'=m=h$=o=u®"d"=k$u+`1!t$u-m!x¥t,"d"[2!o+h`2!h$2^m!m+}2,k;"1",o<
```

1 is the unary digit, prompts you for input

### explanation

```
=d'=m=h$=o=u®"d"=k$u+`1!t$u-m!x¥t,"d"[2!o+h`2!h$2^m!m+}2,k;"1",o<    packed
=d'                                                                  get user input and set it to variable "d"
   =m   =o                                                           set variable "m" and o to 0
     =h$                                                             set variable "h" to 1
          =u®"d"                                                     set variable "u" to length of user input
                =k$u+                                                set variable "k" to u + 1
                     `1                               }2,k           while m < k...
                       !t$u-m                                        set variable "t" to u - m
                             !x¥t,"d"                                get item from user input index t
                                     [2!o+h`2                        add h to variable "o" if x == 1           
                                             !h$2^m                  set variable "h" to the power of m
                                                   !m+               add 1 to m
                                                          ;"1",o<    repeat number 1 o times and print it once finished
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```scala
"*"*Integer.parseInt(_,2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4e7SSbmpFQU5iZp6SjoKSbl5-eWJRnlLszYX5SVmpySUKvkAZhWouBYWU1DSFXCBHI7EovdhKwbGoKLEyOrikKDMvPVbTSiE0L7NEwRasUkGhAChakpOnkaahZGhgaKCkqYkubGBgCAZYpQygOmq5gERZYo5CmpWCBsQqWzsIralgu7S0JE3XYqeSlpKWZ15JanpqkV5BYlFxKpCjEa9jpAmRX1gLoRcsgNAA)